# Returns value in spider_closed signal in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider and I need to return the length of a list inside this spider when finished.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = []

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse values and save in the list
        self.my_list.append(something)

    def closed(self, reason):
        # here I need to return len(self.my_list)
        print len(self.my_list)
```

I tried yield and return, both without success.

Comment: Are you saying you cannot see the output from your print statement?

Comment: No, I see the `print len(self.my_list)`, what I need is to return the value, like `yield Item()` [in examples](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) or something like this.

Comment: What are you going to do with it?

Comment: I want to know the size of that list when my spider ends.

Comment: I understand that but what is wrong with just printing it, if you return something you are going to change how the method works, I would think if you just want to see the value logging it would make more sense

Comment: actually I have an intermediary who executes the spider, it captures the yields of items

Comment: Do you have some idea of how I can make an yield when the queue of requests/parses ends?

Comment: It would yield,  you just don't see it, I would call just another method in closed that took care of whatever it is you want to do